# Any graph $G$ has a $k$-colorable subgraph?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I'm trying to prove that, for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and each simple graph $G=(V,E)$, $G$ has a $k$-colorable subgraph $H=(V',E')$ such that $|E^\prime|\ge (1-1/k)|E|$. I think that i have to use probabilistic method.  First step:  randomly color ever vertex with one of $k$ colors, but how to continue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the expected number of edges with vertices of two different colors?

Comment: Thanks!! the expected number of edges with vertices of two different colors is $(1- 1/k) |E|$